# Where can I find a keyboard viewer for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

How can I find a virtual keyboard viewer for my MacBook Pro running OS X Lion 10.7.5?

Answer (score 7):

Go to `System Preferences -> Keyboard` and check the `Show Keyboard & Character Viewer in menu bar`.

[image]

Now in the menubar you can see a flag icon of the language you're using. Click on it and then click `Show Keyboard Viewer`.

[image]

Now you will have the following virtual keyboard viewer:

[image]

Comment: … or open `/System/Library/Input Methods/KeyboardViewer.app`.

Comment: If you open KeyboardViewer directly (or from an application like Alfred) and close the window by pressing the close button, the process stays open and keeps using about 0-5% CPU.